# Write a function that determine if the string is being supplied represents a correctly delimited Python string literal

Tags: python-3.x, function

For the purpose of this function a valid delimiter is the quotation mark(")or the apostrophe('). Correctly delimited strings must use the same delimiter for the beginning and end character, and that delimiter must not be used within the string. Your function should return the result as a **Boolean value**.

Here are examples of how your function should work.

```
test1 = input("Enter a test string: ") #user enters: "hello worlds"
print(valid_string(test1))             #True
```

It's from my previous test and I received a perfect zero. Can someone show me where to start with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1):

The key to figuring this out is here:

> Correctly delimited strings must use the same delimiter for the beginning and end character, and that delimiter must not be used within the string.

You can check that the string begins with a double quote by doing something like `my_string[0] == '"'`, and similarly for the end by doing `my_string[-1] == '"'`. This works because string[0] and string [-1] will access the first and last characters, respectively. In case you're not aware, negative indexes in Python just mean to start counting from the end (so index -2 would mean the second from the end, etc).

You can then check that no double-quote occurs inside of the string by doing something like this: `my_string[1:-1].count('"') == 0`. This works because my_string[1:-1] takes the part of the string excluding the first and last character, and then count hte number of times that the double quote occurs (zero- it should never occur).

But wait! The single quote can also be a delimiter! I'll leave that as a challenge for you. Hint: make sure the starting and ending delimiter are the same, and also make sure to allow the other delimiter to occur inside of the string. You should also think about handling edge cases with strings that are 0 or 1 characters long. Let me know if any parts of this answer don't make sense or if you would like clarification on something.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you seem to have forgotten to handle length-1 and length-0 inputs.

Comment: I did omit these cases, but the question asks for a starting point for writing such a function, not for a complete solution (otherwise I would have posted code). Thanks for pointing that out, though- I will add a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this should work:

```
def valid_string(s):
    try:
        return s[0] == s[-1] and s[0] in ["'", '"'] and s[0] not in s[1:-1] and len(s) > 1
    except:
        return False


while True:
    test1 = input("Enter a test string: ")
    print(valid_string(test1))
```

This works find for strings less that 2 characters long:

```
$ ./valid_string2.py
Enter a test string: 'adsdasfd"adfadfs'
True
Enter a test string: 'adsfdsafdfs'adsfasd'
False
Enter a test string: "adsfdasf'adsfads"
True
Enter a test string: "adsfasdf"adfasd"
False
Enter a test string: """
False
Enter a test string: "'"
True
Enter a test string: '"'
True
Enter a test string: a
False
Enter a test string: 'a'
True
Enter a test string: "a'
False
Enter a test string: a'
False
Enter a test string: 'a"
False
```

Comment: You didn't handle checking non-endpoint characters, or strings shorter than 2 characters.

Comment: I am not sure what a non-endpoint character is. And it works fine for strings with length less that two.

Comment: Ah I think you mean embedded delimiter.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Now try entering an empty string (hit Enter without typing any characters).

Comment: Is that in the output already? Let me check. Yep that needs to be handled. Updated answer.